# Add custom header on OPTIONS request only

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I want to enable CORS for a subdomain only, so I need to enable it programmatically, I thought doing this would be enough:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But then I noticed that the JS library making the requests, makes an OPTIONS request first, so my code never runs.

Is there anyway to show that I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin in an OPTIONS request, but then allow or disallow it programmatically in a GET request?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do so by writing a module, which is similar to what I described in this blog post,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2014/11/how-to-handle-cors-preflight-requests-in-asp-net-mvcweb-api-with-windows-authentication/